# How to pull data from additional pages through pagination

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I successfully returned the first page of data and have the number of additional pages of data that exist in the API call.

This is the code that I have tried to pull the additional pages of data.

```
try {
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(root + endpoint, params);
const responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
const returnedResults = response.getContentText();
const jsonResults = JSON.parse(returnedResults)
//console.log(responseCode) // *** return 200
//console.log(returnedResults) // *** return successful
//console.log(jsonResults) //*** return successful


Object.keys(jsonResults).forEach(function (key){
  console.log(jsonResults[key]);
  /*
  { count_per_page: 20,
    total_count: 12261,
    current_page: 1,
    total_pages: 614,
    _links: { next: { href: '/v2/organizations?page=2' } } }
  */

  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error: ' + e);
  }

const data = [];

let hasmoreitems = true;
  while (hasmoreitems) {
    
    hasmoreitems = jsonResults.pagination.current_page < jsonResults.pagination.total_pages;
   
  data.forEach(entry => {
    const name = entry['name'];
    const email = entry['email'];
    const mission = entry['mission_statement'];
    const address = entry['address'].country;

  data.push([
    name, email, mission, address]);
  });

  // send data to spreadsheet
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1fM-soJt8rJeIHYZ2vVKyoX9J-LohElqvGB2syhlRk00').getSheets()[1];

  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
  }
```

A sample response for pagination would look like this;

```
"pagination": {
        "count_per_page": 20,
        "total_count": 1,
        "current_page": 1,
        "total_pages": 2,
        "_links": {
            "next": {
                "href": "/v2/organizations?page=2"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the API return a next page token or is the current_page being updated as in your example

Comment: Hello Cooper thanks for your response. I don't believe the API is returning a next page token. It just updates the current page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining the structure of the object, I realized the different levels of the keys. Below is the working code. Hope that helps.

```
let all_data = [];

  while (endpoint) {
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(root + endpoint, params);
    let data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    let orgs = data.organizations

    Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
      console.log(data[key]);
    });

    endpoint = data.pagination._links.next.href;
    orgs.forEach((entry) => {
      all_data.push([
        entry.name,
        entry.email,
        entry.mission_statement,
        entry.address.country,
      ]);
      //console.log(all_data)
    });
       
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult without knowing what your actual response looks like, but I think this will do what you're wanting:

```
let endpoint = "/v2/organizations?page=1";
let all_data = [];
while (endpoint) {
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(root + endpoint, params);
  let data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  endpoint = data._links.next.href;
  data.forEach((entry) => {
    all_data.push([
      entry.name,
      entry.email,
      entry.mission_statement,
      entry.address.country,
    ]);
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding to my question. Unfortunately I am getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined.

Comment: When a change the endpoint to page 2 and console.log the Object keys I get the following:
{ count_per_page: 20,
  total_count: 12309,
  current_page: 2,
  total_pages: 616,
  _links: 
   { previous: { href: '/v2/organizations?page=1' },
     next: { href: '/v2/organizations?page=3' } } }